# static html blog/cms to run on a USB stick?

Tags: html, content-management-system, blogs, portable-applications

What are the options for having a simple blog, content management system that will deploy the full site as static html over FTP/SFTP and any blog API?

I am aware of Thingamablog but it hasn't been updated in more than a year so i guess is dead now. What are my alternatives that *must* export at least static HTML to a FTP server?

It would be nice if the app would have some visual gui to enter the blog post and could run from a USB stick.

Comment: I read this question 3 times to find something programming related...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that [Thingamablog](http://thingamablog.sourceforge.net/) is dead just because it hasn't been updated in a year. Lack of recent updates doesn't necessarily mean the project is dead, it just may mean that it has achieved it's goals and has nothing more to add. Does Thingamablog do what you need?

Comment: Indeed not having releases doesn't mean it is dead, however in the forum the developer announced major new features like a new template engine but it has been more than a year and no beta, no source code, nothing to keep the expectations high...

Comment: I haven't been able to setup the Thingamablog to FTP correctly. After basic setup, on publishing the site it get's stuck with 'Reply 250 Directory successfully changed' in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/). Not a blog or CMS, but it seems to be the kind of thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

Today I came across this tool: [Zeta producer](http://www.zeta-producer.com/index.html). They have a free and a pay version.

Answer (score 0):

Second the motion for CityDesk.  You could probably run your blog on the free version (up to 50 "assets" - files, pages, images, etc.), and publishes static HTML to servers via FTP as its specialty.  It's trivial to add updates; re-publish process does a differential between your new version and the one that's on the server, and only makes necessary changes.

Examples abound - just google for "*.cty" files.
Here's a CityDesk site I help run:

- http://bv-embs-chapter.com

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thingamablog is active again. 1.5 will be released soon, currently 1.5veta5 is the latest. Looks good for what you need.

Paul.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the MoWeS Portable: The Modular Web Server.

http://www.chsoftware.net/en/useware/mowes/mowes.htm

It lets you pick and choose a number of static and dynamic services to run on top of a web server straight off the USB drive or a virtual drive.

I run a Wiki off a virtual drive using Mowes at work and at home, i run a personal blog from my usb stick.

Its verrry easy to configure and powerful enough to be productive.

***Edit:*** Heres a link to help you get started with it:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_on_WOS_Portable_(Windows)

*In the download section, you can select what packages you want to install. This is where you can select what CMS/Blog softwares you want to include.*

Comment: -1. He wants a portable utility for blog management that will export static HTML to a remote FTP, not a portable web server.